# How to change color of a burger menu depending on background?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On the page I have many sections:

```
<section class="white"></section>
<section class="blue-gradient"></section>
<section class="white"></section>
<section class="blue-gradient"></section>
...
```

And I have fixed the burger menu. I need to change color of the burger depending on background section when we scroll. When the burger on white section - the burger is blue, when the burger on blue section - the burger is white.

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using css blend modes: https://getflywheel.com/layout/css-blend-modes/

Comment: @EriksKlotins sorry but it doesn't support IE and change only opposite color. I need to change to any color what I want.

Comment: Check out [this](https://eduardoboucas.com/blog/2017/09/25/svg-clip-path-logo-colour.html). Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at what section is currently visible and toggle the burger menu accordingly:

https://jsfiddle.net/3urpd60s/

```
$(document).on("scroll",function(){

    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop(), 
        elems = $("section"),
        sections = elems.map((i,n)=> $(n).height()),
        tmp = -1, i = 0;

        while(tmp < scrollTop){
           tmp += sections[++i];
        }

    $('#burger').toggleClass("white", !$(elems[--i]).hasClass("white"));    

});
```

Comment: but I found small bug, if section contains some divs it works incorrectly

Comment: You may want to update the question with additional details if there is an issue with my solution.

Comment: Do you have any ideas?